# Twitter Widget isn’t working

Tags: wordpress, twitter, widget

I’m working an internship and the Twitter widget isn’t working on a Wordpress site. I tried changing it out but the original person who developed the theme didn’t put it in any sidebar I can find. I think I found the answer to fix it here (https://www.freshconsulting.com/how-to-fix-your-broken-twitter-stream-widget-on-wordpress/) but I have no access to the cPanel because the login information they gave me isn’t correct.

Is there anyway to swap it out when the theme is outdated without any coding?

Answer (score -1):

If your theme has some specific widget built for Twitter, it is possible that it's out of date and no longer working. Try using a regular HTML widget instead.

Go to https://twitter.com/settings/widgets and make the widget you need, then copy the code it gives you. In WordPress, drag a new HTML widget into your sidebar, and paste the code there.